# Can't check list in script in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Me need check list to lengt, but why it don't work.

I want deteche object, i want make destroy block as minecraft

How i make it:

i set list of objects

if collider touch X object and left button click - destroy target from list in first position, but if X object is X object - don't destroy object in the list

But i get error: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index - if collider touch obejcts: WorldMap, Water, Berries

i can't tell about this in details.
Best review my code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class GetTarget : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Координаты блока")] // block positions
    public int positionX;
    public int positionY;
    public int positionZ;

    [Header("Получение цели")] // set list for block to destroy
    public static List<GameObject> target = new List<GameObject>();

    private void OnTriggerStay(Collider collider)
    {
        target.Insert(0, collider.gameObject);

        if(target[0].name == "WorldMap") // can't destroy world map
        {
            if(target.Count != 0)
            {
                Debug.Log("Вы не можете получить " + target[0]); // you can't get (test message)
                target.Remove(collider.gameObject);  
            }
        }
        if(target[0].name == "Water") // you can't destroy water in structure
        {
            if(target.Count != 0)
            {
                Debug.Log("Вы не можете получить " + target[0]); // you can't get (test message)
                target.Remove(collider.gameObject);  
            }
        }
        if(target[0].name == "Berries") // you can't destroy berries
        {
            if(target.Count != 0)
            {
                Debug.Log("Вы не можете получить " + target[0]); // you can't get (test message)
                target.Remove(collider.gameObject);  
            }
        }
    }

    private void Update() // i get position for collider
    {
        Vector3 positions = transform.position;

        positionX = (int)Mathf.Round(gameObject.transform.position.x);
        positionY = (int)Mathf.Round(gameObject.transform.position.y);
        positionZ = (int)Mathf.Round(gameObject.transform.position.z);

// set position for collider - positions = transfrom.position

        positions.x = positionX;
        positions.y = positionY;
        positions.z = positionZ;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should move the logic to `OnCollisionEnter` and `OnCollisionExit`. With this, you add the `GameObject` in every frame while it is in collision at the very beginning of `OnCollisionStay`.

Comment: I make OnTriggerStay because this not physics collider, i place block to the collider and the collider as checker to destroy blocks

Answer (score 0):

While I can't be certain without line numbers it looks like your error is happening as you remove the target but the top level ifs don't check if the target count is greater then zero.

Your code right now is this

```
if(target[0].name == "WorldMap") // can't destroy world map
```

you should change **all those ifs** to follow this logic

```
if(target.Count() > 0 && target[0].name == "WorldMap") // can't destroy world map
```

that should solve the index out of range exception.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your initial question, the reason you're getting the out of bounds is because in some scenarios, you're removing the last item in the list, but you then still try and check the `target` arrays [0] index. You're removing elements with `target.Remove(collider.gameObject)` which then leaves all following `target[0]` checks being out of range.

A quick cleanup of the code might look something like this:

```cs
public class GetTarget : MonoBehaviour
{
    // These can be assigned as a Vector3Int.
    [Header("Координаты блока")] // block positions
    //public int positionX;
    //public int positionY;
    //public int positionZ;
    public Vector3Int position;


    [Header("Получение цели")] // set list for block to destroy
    public static List<GameObject> target = new ();

    // You probably only want to check for this when the collider first makes contact.
    private void OnTriggerEnter ( Collider collider )
    {
        /*
            Shouldn't you be checking an object's tag, not the object name?
            e.g.
            if ( collider.CompareTag( "WorldMap" ) ) { ... }
        */
        if ( collider.gameObject.name == "WorldMap" ||
            collider.gameObject.name == "Water" ||
            collider.gameObject.name == "Berries" )
        {
            Debug.Log ( $"Вы не можете получить {collider.gameObject.name}" ); // you can't get (test message)
            return;
        }

        // I don't know why you need to insert at index 0, so I won't change it.
        target.Insert ( 0, collider.gameObject );
    }

    private void Update ( ) // i get position for collider
    {
        var pos = transform.position;
        position = new Vector3Int ( 
            ( int ) Mathf.Round ( pos.x ), 
            ( int ) Mathf.Round ( pos.y ), 
            ( int ) Mathf.Round ( pos.z ) ) ;

        // I THINK you wanted to then assign the rounded position to the transform position:
        transform.position = position;
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of `( int ) Mathf.Round` you can use [`Mathf.RoundToInt`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.RoundToInt.html) .. and in general even further you could simply use [`transform.position = Vector3Int.RoundToInt(transform.position);`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3Int.RoundToInt.html) ;)

Comment: Sounds like in general the `target` could rather be a `Queue<GameObject>` if it is about order .. or a `HashSet` if it is about uniqueness .. or not be a collection at all ^^